# What is the difference between 喝 and 饮?

Tags: usage, meaning

Both 喝 and 饮 seem to mean 'to drink', but is there nuance beyond this?

Comment: They are interchangeable in modern Chinese, 喝 is used more widely. 饮 is mostly used in written language or official documents, as well as some old sayings such as idioms, while 喝 is mainly used for speaking language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

饮 is more of a classical term which mostly exists in established words and phrases:

- As verb: 饮酒, 饮水思源，饮鸩止渴, 饮泣, 饮恨, etc.
- As (part of) noun: 饮品, 饮料, 饮片, 饮具, 冷饮, 饮食, 饮用水, etc.

Use 喝 in everywhere else.

Usually you don't create words and phrases with 饮. I tried a few and they all sound funny:

- 饮可乐, 饮咖啡, 饮西北风, 饮汤 -- DON'T EVER USE THESE.

Comment: For what it's worth, using 喝 in place of 饮 in all those examples actually sounds wrong in Cantonese. Wonder if this regional difference crops up in any other regional off-shoots of Chinese.

Comment: *饮可乐, 饮咖啡, , 饮汤 -- DON'T EVER USE THESE* these phrases are all correct in Cantonese.   In Hong Kong, 喝可乐, 喝咖啡 and 喝汤 are all literal terms, only used in written form.

Answer (score 1):

The clue is in 飲食 and 吃喝

In Mandarin, 吃喝 is more colloquial and 飲食 is more literal, (it is the other way around in Cantonese)

**In practical usage**:

Both 飲  and 喝 can be a verb for "to drink"  for example: 飲湯，飲酒，飲水; 喝湯，喝酒，喝水

But 喝  can also be a verb for "to shout" http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/230/ , for example: 呼喝，大喝, 喝止

- Since 飲 as a verb can only means "to drink" we can easily add adverb  to modify it , for example :  狂飲，痛飲, 暢飲，but it would be difficult for 喝, for example:  大喝 can means" freely drink" or  " loudly shout"
- 飲 can be  (part of) a noun for "beverage", for example: 冷飲，熱飲, 飲品; 喝 cannot.

**In summary**:

- As a verb for " to drink", 飲 and 喝 are interchangeable.
- 飲 is more colloquial and 喝 is more literal. (Cantonese)
- 喝 is more colloquial and 飲 is more literal. (Mandarin)
- 飲 can be part of a noun; 喝 cannot.

Comment: I guess this is on Cantonese? In mandarin, as Wang Dingwei said, it's the opposite. 喝 is colloquial and 飲 is classical.

Comment: yes, in Cantonese it is as I said 飲 is more colloquial and 喝 is more literal, I will add it to my answer